# Strong attachment point on drywall in front of 1.5" thick stud in front of concrete

Tags: concrete, walls, studs, hanging

I'm looking at attaching a hammock to the wall in the basement of a 1960s-built house, USA. The wall is drywall, in front of some wooden framing that I think is nailed to the concrete foundation wall behind it. I am pretty certain that the wooden studs are side-on. The distance between the drywall and the concrete is only 1.5". If you're familiar with this kind of construction, your input would be great as my stud-finder is having a very hard time.

If it were a regular stud, I would follow the instructions in my wall-hanging kit (not very DIY, I know): I would drill a 3" long, 5/16" diameter pilot hole into the stud, then use a single 3" long, 3/8" diameter lag bolt to attach the anchor to the wall.

**Question:** How would you attach an anchor point for a hammock to this wall? Also, do you expect the wall studs on this basement wall to be strong enough?

I see my three options as (a) just replace the 3" bolt with a ~2" bolt, (b) use multiple ~2" screws/bolts into the stud at multiple points, (c) use something that goes through the stud into the concrete behind it. I would prefer (a) > (b) > (c) if it is safe.

Background: DIY novice.

Comment: `do you expect the wall studs on this basement wall to be strong enough?`  ... I would not expect any stud in any basement to be strong enough ... expecting is the same as assuming ... that can lead to failure ... do not expect, make sure instead

Comment: @jstola "make sure" is good advice. Maybe I should have written "would these be as strong as any other typical studs?" A positive answer does not guarantee it will work. But a negative answer, like I got, saves the hassle of trying something doomed.

Comment: Would you be OK with another member being visible outside the drywall?  You could get a 4x4 or double 2x4 and anchor it at the top of the wall (ceiling) if you can find a joist, and the floor.

Comment: @Huesmann definitely worth considering, but I think I'd prefer a concrete anchor at that point.

Comment: And actually, I already put in a 3/8" by 5" concrete anchor and it seems to have worked. I'll test its strength before use.

Comment: @usul (tell me of your homeworld) the anchor is in the concrete foundation wall?  What kind of anchor did you use?

Comment: @Huesmann (it rains every day) - yes, it is through the wood into the concrete. Essentially this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-8-in-x-5-in-Wedge-Anchor-40-Pack-499TS40/312742467

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not trust the studs to be anchored to the concrete enough to take weight, they might just have enough nails or glue to hold the drywall up.

Drill right into the concrete and use concrete anchors to hold the bolts.

Comment: My basement has the same setup, the studs are not anchored to the concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Those studs are not studs, they are just spacers to separate the drywall from concrete and maybe allow for some insulation.

Hammock needs to carry quite a weight so you need to anchor it in the concrete wall.

Be sure there are no electrical or plumbing in the way.

Comment: Thank you, clear answer. I will accept the other one because it was earlier, but I appreciate your reply!

Comment: @usul just because he types faster :(